# Doing a loop(for) in variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Ok, i need to set a lot of colors for an graphic and put the colors (array) inside a loop.

It's for a plugin (Chart.js), and i want to display different colors in the graphic.

I tried this:

```
var gra = [
        {
            for (i = 0; i < color.length; i++)
                {
                    value: 30,
                    color:color[i]
                }
        },
    ];
```

I have an array with all colors.

Comment: That isn't valid JavaScript at all. You are doing many things wrong. You have a loop inside a object, and inside the loop you have invalid statements.

Comment: You cannot add a loop structure at random places in your code. Either use an anonymous function or pre build the list

Comment: I urge you to familiarize yourself with the fundamentals of JavaScript syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is something like this what you are looking for?

```js
var gra, i, count;

gra = [];

for (i = 0, count = color.length; i < count; i++) {
  gra[i] = { value: 30, color: color[i] };
}
```

Comment: Wow! Is that what i need. Thank you. Just one more question: How i do one loop for the "value". The "value" number is different. Example: Maybe it is 30 and 70, like a graphic.

Comment: Sure, I'll be happy to update my answer with this, but you will have to be more specific about where you are getting the "value" values from. Do you have another array like your "color" array?

Comment: The value probably came from a database after some math. The right way to do this (plugin): http://www.chartjs.org/docs/ . But i really don't know how i do the math to display different values for different "topics".

Comment: Ah, OK. I'm not really familiar with the chart.js logic. I would suggest asking this as an additional question.

Answer (score 2):

This won't work at all. What you haven isn't even valid JavaScript. You cannot add a `for` loop inside an object, and what you have inside the loop aren't valid statements.

Do this instead:

```
var gra = [];

for(var i = 0; i < color.length; i++) {
    gra.push({
        value: 30,
        color: color[i]
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `forEach`

```
var gra = [];

colors.forEach(function (color) {
    gra.push({
        'value': 30,
        'color': color;
    });
}
```